# recieving wierd math error in simple factoral code, don't know why

Tags: c, math

i am making a simple factoral program here, and for some reason it is giving me really strange answers here ..

i don't know if i have done something wrong here or not. can somebody please explain the error and why it happens?

example: when i enter 5 it returns -1899959296

```
#include <stdio.h>


void factor(int total);

int main (){

printf("enter a number \n");

int val;
scanf("%i", &val);


factor(val);


  }

 void factor (int total){

for (int count = 1; count<=total; count++ ){
    total = total * count;
}

printf("%d", total);

}
```

Comment: Google "integer overflow in C".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition for the loop to end is `count<=total`. But in each iteration, the value of `total` increases gradually. Thus, the loop goes on executing many times and breaks when `total` becomes less than `count`. This *can* happen when `total` overflows.

To fix the problem, use a different variable for calculating the factorial.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable for calculating your calculation and condition which leads to integer overflow.

```
for (int count = 1; count<=total; count++ ){
   total = total * count;
}
```

you are checking the condition using the total, in loop you are incrementing that. This is the reason for that.

Use another variable for this.

```
 int output=total;
```

then make the condition like this,

```
 output=output*count;
```

And print `printf("%d\n",output);`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int count = 1; count<=total; count++ )
{
    total = total * count;
}
```

because you are comparing with changing value of total, take new variable for factor value

```
unsigned int factor = 1;
    for (count = 1; count <= total; count++ )
    {
        factor = factor * count;
    }
printf("%u\n\n",factor);
```

also note that for big number you factor variable size is enough to hold factor count